# recursive removal of elements in array

Tags: algorithm

Given an array of n elements, remove any adjacent pair of elements which are equal. Repeat this operation until there are no more adjacent pairs to remove; that will be the final array.

For e.g `1 2 2 3 4` should return the array `1 3 4.`
please note array need not to be sorted.

check this test case also: `1,2,2,3,4,4,3,5` o/p should be `1,5`.
(2,2) and (4,4) gets removed, then (3,3) which became adjacent after the removal of (4,4)

Comment: The array is always sorted ? `1 2 2 2 3 4`(three 2) will return `1 3 4` or `1 2 3 4` ?

Comment: @ muggen 1,2,2,3,4,4,3 please check this scenario...

Comment: @prp, regarding the edit, so you want after the first iteration and removal, to remove the new adjacent pairs that occur now? and continue that until no adjacent-pairs are left?

Comment: @muggen as i said array need not to be sorted so any set of adjacent pairs need to be removed...

Comment: I'm not following you now. Please precisely define adjacent.

Comment: In the example of `1,2,2,3,4,4,3,5` why should `3` be removed? It is not adjacent prior to the removal of `4,4`. You need to state in the definition that this is a recursive removal I believe.

Comment: Your question is very confusing.

Comment: @David: please don't apply the homework tag w/o asking the original poster. (even though this probably is)

Comment: @jasons: Sorry.  You are right.  I am unable to remove the tag currently (all I have is "link | flag").

Comment: @David: homework tag removed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any time you remove a pair of elements, you also need to see if you generated another pair that you want to remove.

The algorithm should follow naturally from that observation.

Comment: Following the same idea, I think you could also solve this using a stack. Every time the element to be pushed on the stack is equal to the top of the stack, just pop.

Comment: @anothem, exactly! (I actually didn't realize that.)

Answer (score 1):

In Python:

```
>>> l=[1,2,2,3,4,4,3,5]
>>> [x for x in l if not l.count(x) > 1]
[1, 5]
```

This removes all integers that occur more than once in the list. This is a correct result *for your example* but I think that you are really trying to state something different. I think you are saying:

```
list:=(an unsorted list of integers)
while adjacent_pairs(list) is True:
    remove_adjacent_pairs(list)
```

Once again, in Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def dedupe_adjacent(l):
    for i in xrange(len(l) - 1, 0, -1):
        if l[i] == l[i-1]:
            del l[i-1:i+1]
            return True

    return False

def process_list(l):
    print "input list: ",l
    i=1
    while(dedupe_adjacent(l)):
        print "   loop ",i,":",l
        i+=1

    print "processed list=",l    
    print 

process_list([1,2,2,3,4,4,3,5])
process_list([1,2,2,3,4,4,6,3,5])
```

Output:

```
input list:  [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 5]
   loop  1 : [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5]
   loop  2 : [1, 2, 2, 5]
   loop  3 : [1, 5]
processed list= [1, 5]

input list:  [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 6, 3, 5]
   loop  1 : [1, 2, 2, 3, 6, 3, 5]
   loop  2 : [1, 3, 6, 3, 5]
processed list= [1, 3, 6, 3, 5]
```

Comment: in my problem all adjacent pairs are removed.many people have confusion why 3 will be removed in my test case ,because upon removal of pair of 4 ,3 makes a pair so it will also be removed.so i think we csn do it using stack.

Comment: This correctly handles the removal of the pair of 3's after the removal of the pair of 4's I don't understand the comment?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the stack based algorithm based upon the edited question.

```
// pseudo code, not tested
void RemoveDupp(vector<int> & vin, vector<int> & vout)
{
    int i = 0, int j = -1;
    vout.resize(vin.size());

    while (i < vin.size())
    {
        if (j == -1 || vout[j] != vin[i])
            vout[++j] = vin[i++]; //push
        else
            j--, i++;             //pop
    }
    vout.resize(j + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following:

```
function compress(arr) {
    var prev, res = [];
    for (var i in arr) {
        if (i == 0 || (arr[i] != arr[i - 1]))
            res.push(arr[i]);
    }
    return res;
}
compress([1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8]);
```

Returns:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Also (JavaScript 1.6 solution):

```
[1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8].filter(function(el, i, arr) {
    return i == 0 || (el != arr[i - 1]);
})
```

**Edit:** Removing any item that appears in the array more than once requires a different solution:

```
function dedup(arr) {
    var res = [], seen = {};
    for (var i in arr)
        seen[arr[i]] = seen[arr[i]] ? ++seen[arr[i]] : 1;
    for (var j in arr) {
        if (seen[arr[j]] == 1)
            res.push(arr[j]);
    }
    return res;
}
```

The following:

```
dedup([1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 5]);
```

Produces:

```
[1, 5]
```

Comment: i have not edited question ,i have given another test case to make it more clear..

Answer (score 0):

The following Python 3 code will remove duplicates from a list (array).  It does this by scanning the array from start towards end and compares the target element with the element one larger.  If they are the same they are removed.  If the element pointer is not pointing at 0, then it is reduced by 1 in order to catch nested pairs.  If the two compared elements are different then the pointer is incremented.

I'm sure there's a more pythonic way to remove two adjacent elements from a list, but I'm new to Python and haven't figured that out yet.  Also, you'll want to get rid of the `print(indx, SampleArray)` statement--I left it in there to let you follow the progress in the output listing below.

```
# Algorithm to remove duplicates in a semi-sorted list

def CompressArray(SampleArray):
    indx=0

    while(indx < len(SampleArray)-1):
        print(indx, SampleArray)
        if(SampleArray[indx]==SampleArray[indx+1]):
            del(SampleArray[indx])
            del(SampleArray[indx])
            if(indx>0):
                indx-=1
        else:
            indx+=1
    return SampleArray
```

Here are sample runs for:

- [1, 2, 2, 3, 4]
- [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 5]
- [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8]
- [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 7, 6, 4, 3, 8, 8, 5, 9, 10, 10, 9, 11]
- [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6, 6, 5, 7, 8, 8, 7, 4, 9]

```
================================
0 [1, 2, 2, 3, 4]
1 [1, 2, 2, 3, 4]
0 [1, 3, 4]
1 [1, 3, 4]
[1, 3, 4]
================================
0 [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 5]
1 [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 5]
0 [1, 3, 4, 4, 3, 5]
1 [1, 3, 4, 4, 3, 5]
2 [1, 3, 4, 4, 3, 5]
1 [1, 3, 3, 5]
0 [1, 5]
[1, 5]
================================
0 [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8]
1 [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8]
0 [1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8]
1 [1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8]
0 [1, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8]
1 [1, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8]
0 [1, 4, 3, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8]
1 [1, 4, 3, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8]
2 [1, 4, 3, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8]
1 [1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8]
2 [1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8]
3 [1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8]
4 [1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8]
5 [1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8]
[1, 4, 5, 6, 7]
================================
0 [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 7, 6, 4, 3, 8, 8, 5, 9, 10, 10, 9, 11]
1 [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 7, 6, 4, 3, 8, 8, 5, 9, 10, 10, 9, 11]
0 [1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 7, 6, 4, 3, 8, 8, 5, 9, 10, 10, 9, 11]
1 [1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 7, 6, 4, 3, 8, 8, 5, 9, 10, 10, 9, 11]
2 [1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 7, 6, 4, 3, 8, 8, 5, 9, 10, 10, 9, 11]
3 [1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 7, 6, 4, 3, 8, 8, 5, 9, 10, 10, 9, 11]
4 [1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 7, 6, 4, 3, 8, 8, 5, 9, 10, 10, 9, 11]
3 [1, 3, 4, 6, 6, 4, 3, 8, 8, 5, 9, 10, 10, 9, 11]
2 [1, 3, 4, 4, 3, 8, 8, 5, 9, 10, 10, 9, 11]
1 [1, 3, 3, 8, 8, 5, 9, 10, 10, 9, 11]
0 [1, 8, 8, 5, 9, 10, 10, 9, 11]
1 [1, 8, 8, 5, 9, 10, 10, 9, 11]
0 [1, 5, 9, 10, 10, 9, 11]
1 [1, 5, 9, 10, 10, 9, 11]
2 [1, 5, 9, 10, 10, 9, 11]
3 [1, 5, 9, 10, 10, 9, 11]
2 [1, 5, 9, 9, 11]
1 [1, 5, 11]
[1, 5, 11]
================================
0 [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6, 6, 5, 7, 8, 8, 7, 4, 9]
0 [2, 3, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6, 6, 5, 7, 8, 8, 7, 4, 9]
1 [2, 3, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6, 6, 5, 7, 8, 8, 7, 4, 9]
0 [2, 2, 4, 5, 6, 6, 5, 7, 8, 8, 7, 4, 9]
0 [4, 5, 6, 6, 5, 7, 8, 8, 7, 4, 9]
1 [4, 5, 6, 6, 5, 7, 8, 8, 7, 4, 9]
2 [4, 5, 6, 6, 5, 7, 8, 8, 7, 4, 9]
1 [4, 5, 5, 7, 8, 8, 7, 4, 9]
0 [4, 7, 8, 8, 7, 4, 9]
1 [4, 7, 8, 8, 7, 4, 9]
2 [4, 7, 8, 8, 7, 4, 9]
1 [4, 7, 7, 4, 9]
0 [4, 4, 9]
[9]
================================
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution to this in Java. You need to use [replaceAll](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method in String class in Java. You can use regular expession to remove such adjacent redundant characters:

```
public class MyString {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    String str = "12234435";

    while(!str.replaceAll("(\\w)\\1+", "").equalsIgnoreCase(str))
      str = str.replaceAll("(\\w)\\1+", "");

    System.out.println(str);
  }
}
```

You can find how to give a regular expression [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum)

Answer (score 0):

I would:

1. Sort the array.
2. From the start of the array, until you are at the last element of the array do:

   1. `count` = count the number of array[i] elements.
   2. remove the first `count` elements of the array if `count` > 1.

Comment: This does not work. What about `1,3,1,1`? Sorts to `1,1,1,3` Three 1's are removed, leaving `3`. Not what is specified (if I understand the poorly written question...) The deletions are supposed to be pairwise duplicates...

Comment: According to the question: "check this test case also: 1,2,2,3,4,4,3,5 o/p should be 1,5."  Note that 3 is deleted in this case.  The test cases the OP gives seem to point to "delete all occurrences of a number if that number appears more than once."

Comment: But also states `remove any adjacent pair of elements which are equal such that the resultant array also doesn't contain any adjacent duplicate elements.` The two threes are removed because they are pair-wise after the removal of the two fours. Granted, the example IS correctly generated by simple removal of all duplicate elements; but if you read his text I don't *think* that is what he is after...

Answer (score 0):

I love Java, but functional solutions should get more time on this site.
In Haskell, doing things the way the question asks:

```
compress lst = if (length lst == length b) then lst else (compress b) where
    b = helper lst
    helper [] = []
    helper [x] = [x]
    helper (x:y:xs) = if (x == y) then (helper xs) else (x:helper (y:xs))
```

You can solve this problem in O(n) time, although it is a bit more complicated

```
compress' lst = reverse (helper [] lst) where
    helper xs [] = xs
    helper [] (x:xs) = helper [x] xs
    helper (a:as) (x:xs)
        | a == x = helper as xs
        | otherwise = helper (x:a:as) xs
```

Answer (score 0):

I think we could use a stack to check adjacent duplicated elements.
Scan the array. For each new element, if it is equal to the top element in the stack, drop it and pop the top element from the stack. Otherwise, push it into the stack.